# laravel filament production on cpanel

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am trying to deploy laravel with filament but CSS/js not loading when I checked the view source of the page css/js url is different
on main site css/js is https://example.com/admin/public/js/filament/support/async-alpine.js?v=3.0.0.0 which is not loading and when I removed /admin then css/js is loading but don't know how to fix it as it doesn't exist in my resources folder.

Please advice how to fix it? also any good resource for deploying laravel in production mode

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you should modify the APP_URL in the .env:

```
APP_URL=https://example.com
```

For the Filament assets, you might need to republish them:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=filament-assets
```

If you want to automate deployments, Laravel Forge is a great option: https://forge.laravel.com